# Confusing relation between distance cost and angle in SIoU Loss (Scylla-IoU Loss)

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

It would be appreciated if anyone is able to explain why distance cost is positive related with the angle alpha in SIoU Loss.

The paper [SIoU Loss](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.12740) says that distance cost should increase with larger alpha value:

[image: Distance cost should increase with larger alpha value]

However the fact maybe on the contrary according to the equations in the paper. The proof steps are:
[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2 and 3]

Is any step of this proof wrong?